# How to extract a value from an array in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm new with powershell and I'm pretty sure my question is quite easy for experts. I have a CSV file with this table. [image]

I want to write a script where I give a variable $name, and get its state if it exists in the machine column.
I tried to do something like this:

```
    $csv=Import-Csv C:\data.csv -Delimiter=","
foreach ($row in $csv){

$machine=$row.Machine
If ($machine=$searched_name){
    $searched_state=$row.State}

}
```

But this clearly does not work.

Anyone can help me please ?

Thanks. !

Comment: How about: `Import-Csv C:\data.csv | Where-Object { $_.Machine -eq "m1" }`

Comment: just FYI - this >>> `If ($machine=$searched_name){` <<< is an _assignment_, not a _comparison_. [*grin*] you need to use `-eq` instead of `=`.

Comment: Import-csv returns an object with properties, methods and so on. I advise you to explore it using Get-Member and according wat you get, start processing it according your needs with Select-object and/or Foreach-object

Comment: In addition to what @Lee_Dailey said, you should not use the `=` on a parameter as well like you do in `-Delimiter=","` Use a space instead. Besides, if the delimiter used is a comma, you can leave that out entirely, because a comma is the default.

Comment: @Theo - i think the delimiter used depends on the locale. from what i have been told, the `;` is the default in some locales - kinda like the use of `,` instead of `.` for numeric delims.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey That is true for Excel. For the export/import csv cmdlets the default delimiter is always a comma. So if you're in a country like me (the Netherlands), the locales listseparator is the semi-colon `;` and that is what **Excel** expects on open and uses when exporting to csv. The PowerShell cmdlets however still use the comma as default. A handy switch on those cmdlets is `-UseCulture` that will adapt the delimiter to what is set in the locale settings so even Excel understands. If only it could be just as easy in Excel... ;)

Comment: @Theo - thank you for the info! [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, try this, I think it's what you're looking for. Note that I'm using `ConvertFrom-Csv` instead of importing it from a file but for your test case you can just remove that part and import your Csv as you normally do.

```
# Use this instead of ConvertFrom-Csv
# $csv = Import-Csv C:\data.csv

$csv = @'
Machine,State
m1,0
m2,1
m3,2
m4,3
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$question = $null

while($question -ne 'X')
{
    Clear-Host
    $question = Read-Host "Enter Machine Name to query or 'X' to Exit"
    
    if($question -eq 'x')
    {
        break
    }
    
    $val = $csv.where({$_.Machine -eq $question}).State
    
    if(-not $val)
    {
        "`nMachine Name '$question' could not be found in CSV file."
        "Press Enter to restart the loop."
        Read-Host
        continue
    }

    "`nState for '$question' is '$val'.`n"
    "Press Enter to restart the loop."
    Read-Host 
}
```